# Which questions on SP go to this site and which to SO?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation

I am confused to see the flux of new questions (and answers) on SharePoint in SO ( http://stackoverflow.com ) no less than here.
They are not moved to this site as well as I could not find any explanation (in [About page](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/about)) what is this site for in comparison to questions on Sharepoint in http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Which questions on Sharepoint should be asked in this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com and which in http://stackoverflow.com ?

Answer (score 2):

If a question is SharePoint related, including programming questions, please ask it on https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/.

Stack Overflow (http://stackoverflow.com) is intended for questions on programming in general. SharePoint development questions are therefore perfectly permissible on Stack Overflow, but you probably have a better chance of getting it answered on SharePoint.StackExchange.

The moderators on Stack Overflow are very receptive to suggestions to migrate questions that are SharePoint-specific, but there is no mechanism to automatically migrate SharePoint questions to SharePoint.StackExchange.com. Stack Overflow has a much larger number of users and amount of traffic (it was the original site in the Stack Exchange family) so inevitably a significant number of SharePoint questions get posted there. In addition there is a large body of SharePoint questions that were posted before SharePoint.StackExchange existed.
Ultimately it is up to the poster to decide where to post, but if you want an answer to a specific SharePoint question you have a better chance of getting an answer on SharePoint.StackExchange.com.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm still confused. If SO "is intended for questions on programming in general" then what is http://programmers.stackexchange.com for?

Comment: That question you will need to ask of the Programmers.StackExchange community (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: Programmers.SE is for programming questions which may have a lot of discussion... for example, asking for opinions.